# C# Selenium using proxy with chrome's profile

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

I want to open chrome with my profile and proxy. This code is chaning my IP fine:

```
string IPtoUse = richTextBox2.Lines[0];
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        /*options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Kamil\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");*/
        var proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
        proxy.IsAutoDetect = false;
        proxy.HttpProxy =
        proxy.SslProxy = IPtoUse;
        options.Proxy = proxy;
        options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
        var Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);


        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address");
```

When i add the line:

```
options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Kamil\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
```

Program start ignore the proxy. What am I doing wrong? Also I would like to ask you guys how can I change the line:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

To make program pause but don't freeze it. thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

It might be erroring out on you due to the user data line.  It should be as follows:

```
options.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Kamil\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem with the pause is that your pausing your main thread, you have to make another thread and put all your code on that thread.

```
public static void DoWork()
{

//put all your code in here, and you then you can pause it without  it freezing

}

public static void StartWorker()
{
    Thread worker = new Thread(DoWork);
    worker.IsBackground = true;
    worker.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
    worker.Start()
}
```